# Django URL to Template View Preventing Media Folder from Displaying

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been working on a Django DRF/Vue project and ran into issues with being able to download or view files from the media folder. I have this set up as a media root and directory in the settings and included the following in my url.py file:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(
          settings.STATIC_URL,
          document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT
     )

urlpatterns += static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL,
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

The issue is happening from my path to the template views.

```
re_path(r"^.*$", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point")
```

If I comment this line out, the media directory works as I want but this causes my application to no longer direct users to my frontend and Django template files. I am fairly new to Django and am not sure exactly how to resolve this, or if it is possible to create a condition within the path to exclude /media from being triggered?

**Edit:** I was able to make this somewhat work by changing `re_path(r"^.*$", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point")` to `path('', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point")`. My app currently runs Django on port 8000 and Vue app on port 8080. I access the app front end from 8080, which allows it to re-direct to the login page if necessary. If I try to refresh any page with this updated config, I am faced with the error, "Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:"... and it shows a list of my api URLs. I find URL patterns with Django one of the most confusing things about trying to learn this framework. Can someone please explain to me what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck on this for a long time and finally figured it out. Of course it was a really simple fix. All I had to do, after changing the 're_path' to 'path' was change the Vue route type to hash instead of history.